# Sanitize html inside <Text> using this.props.children

Tags: react-native

I am having an issue where I have a text component that manages to style and does the rendering of text. To render the text, I receive this.props.children which are passed values. The values need to be sanitized of HTML and displayed in the Text component so I am wondering if there is a way to do this in with . When I try to use , the text does not display because this.props.children is not HTML.

Any suggestions as to how to approach this issue? This is done in React-Native
Here is what I am using to pass to my component which is being passed 'text' from another component:

```
<View style={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <Montserrat
              regular
              style={{
                marginTop: 15,
                color: config.colors.commentText,
                fontSize: 14,
                lineHeight: 20,
                fontWeight: "400",
                paddingLeft: 50,
                paddingRight: 50
              }}
            >
              {this.props.text}
            </Montserrat>
          </View>
```

Here us my text component when gets passed text values:

```
export class Montserrat extends React.Component {
  base = "Montserrat";

  defaultStyle = {
    color: config.colors.darkText,
    fontSize: 22,
    lineHeight: 30,
  };

  getFontFamily = () => {
    const base = "Montserrat"
    if (this.props.light) {
      return `${base}-Light`
    }

    if (this.props.medium) {
      return `${base}-Medium`
    }

    if(this.props.semiBold) {
      return `${base}-SemiBold`
    }

    if(this.props.regular) {
      return `${base}-Regular`;
    }

    return base;
  }

  render() {
    const style = { ...this.defaultStyle, ...this.props.style, fontFamily: this.getFontFamily() };

    return <Text style={style} {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</Text>;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! It would be great if you provide an example of your code that isn't working ([mcve])

Comment: I just added my text component. Thanks!

Comment: Add example usage as well. This isn't enough to reproduce the problem.  I can copy paste the code and throw in a random string of HTML and it will render ([my attempt to reproduce in Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kameyin/stackoverflow-q-49518394-148212)).